# How do I get the internal SQL Server database version number of an .MDF database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to get the internal database version number of a SQL Server database programatically to determine which SQL Server instance to use.

i.e. SQL Server 2008 - Version 661, SQL Server 2008 R2 -  Version 665

I have found an article: http://rusanu.com/2011/04/04/how-to-determine-the-database-version-of-an-mdf-file/ that shows the location of the version number as the DWORD value at offset 0×12064 in the `.mdf` file.

How can I get this information programatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the database is already attached:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #d
(
  ParentObject NVARCHAR(4000),
  [Object] NVARCHAR(4000),
  Field NVARCHAR(4000),
  VALUE NVARCHAR(4000)
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'dbcc page(' + RTRIM(DB_ID()) 
  + ',1,9,3) with tableresults;'

INSERT #d EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT [Version] = VALUE FROM #d WHERE Field = N'dbi_version';

DROP TABLE #d;
```

Though if the database is already attached, then it is already at the version of the instance. If the database isn't attached, why not just attach it to the most recent version you have? Just because the database is currently 661 does not mean it has to stay that way. It will work if you attach it to 2008 R2 or 2012 just as well.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble attaching an SQL Server 2008 database to an SQL Server 2012 instance. Is this a different case? This is what prompted me to ask this question. I haven't been able to upgrade the version. Are downgrades even supported at all?

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read the last line of your post. I still have issues attaching older versions to a newer instance though...

Comment: @J2Tuner what are "issues" and how much "older" are you talking about? You can't attach 2000 to 2012, for example, but anything more recent than 2000 should be fine on the newest you've got.

Comment: If I tryto attach a database that was created in SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008, it gives me an error message that says: "The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported." I see though that I do not have any trouble upgrading (although I was sure I did at some point).

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "on the newest you've got." You can't go backwards.

Comment: I would still like to be able to know what version the file is so that I could use the correct connection string to connect to a specific instance of SQL Server with multiple instances installed on one machine. As far as I know, you cannot have the same name for multiple instances.

Comment: You'll have to parse the file contents (sorry, I don't know how to do that offhand). However I don't understand why you don't just attach any databases to your SQL Server 2012 instance. If you have a problem attaching a 2008 database to 2012, let's investigate that, because you shouldn't.

Comment: The idea behind being able to select a specific server instance based on file version is so that I can make sure that my computer that has SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 instances will not open a 2008 file in 2012. I do not want to do this specifically on this machine because I have other machines running Windows XP which only supports SQL Server 2008. I do not want to automatically upgrade the file version and render them useless on the XP machines.

Comment: I do not seem to be having any issues at this time upgrading a 2008 file to 2012, but this is on a computer that has both 2008 and 2012 installed. Is there a chance that a computer that does not have 2008 installed, but only 2012 can give me an issue?

Comment: @J2Tuner I've never heard of such an issue, no. Upgrading the file by attaching it to SQL Server 2012 has no dependency on another version of SQL Server being present. As to your XP issue, well, XP is 12 years old, maybe it's time to cut the cord? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stored procedure I created to read the offline .mdf using OLE Automation and ADO's Stream object. This solution and more context are posted here as well: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3de5b574-0751-44a2-b69f-fa0c20378359/how-to-determine-sql-server-version-of-an-mdf-file?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

```
CREATE /*ALTER*/ PROCEDURE spDBVersion
(
@FilePath nvarchar(500) /*Your filepath here EG 'C:\SQLData\somedatabase.mdf'*/
)
AS

DECLARE @HR int,
        @objStream int,
        @strErrorMessage Varchar(1000),
        @Source nvarchar(255),
        @Desc nvarchar(255),
        @offset bigint,
        @binary1 binary,
        @binary2 binary

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT @strErrorMessage='Creating ADO stream object'
EXEC @HR = sp_OACreate  'ADODB.Stream' , @objStream OUT
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @strErrorMessage='Opening ADO stream'
EXEC @HR = sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Open'
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @strErrorMessage='Declaring ADO stream type binary'
EXEC @HR = sp_OASetProperty @objStream, 'Type', 1
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @strErrorMessage='Opening File into ADO stream'
EXEC @HR = sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'LoadFromFile', NULL , @FilePath
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @offset = 73828 --9 * 8192 + 96 + 4

SELECT @strErrorMessage='Setting offset to read file'
EXEC @HR = sp_OASetProperty @objStream, 'Position',  @offset
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @strErrorMessage = 'Reading Version number from mdf'
EXEC @HR = sp_OAMethod @objstream, 'Read', @binary1 OUT , 1
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @strErrorMessage = 'Reading Version number from mdf'
EXEC @HR = sp_OAMethod @objstream, 'Read', @binary2 OUT , 1
IF @HR <> 0 GOTO CLEANUP

SELECT @binary1 + 256 * @binary2 AS DatabaseVersion

END_ROUTINE:
RETURN

CLEANUP:
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objStream,
        @Source OUT,
        @Desc OUT;
        SELECT ErrorInSP='spDBVersion',
        HR = convert(varbinary(4),@HR),
        Source=@Source,
        Description=@Desc,
        Process=@strErrorMessage
    GOTO END_ROUTINE
END
GO
```

This Stored Procedure Requires OLE Automation, so you'll want to wrap it in some reconfigure statements assuming OLE is disabled (as it probably should be).

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

exec spDBVersion 'E:\SQLData\somedatabase.mdf'


GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
```